# How to change zimbra login screen logo height?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, compatibility, zimbra

I have prepared a login image for my new e-mail system (Zimbra). Then I have changed hhe contents of file `/opt/zimbra/jetty/webapps/zimbra/skins/_base/base3/skin.properties`

```
...
90 LoginH1 = margin:0 0 30px 30px;
91 LoginAppName = display:none;
92 LoginLabelColor = @TxtC@
93 LoginButton = @ButtonShadowDefault@ border:1px solid @ButtonBorderColor@;
94 LoginBannerImg = @LogoImgDir@/LoginBanner.png?v=@jsVersion@

//95 LoginBanner = @img(, LoginBannerImg, 450px, 36px)@ //old
95 LoginBanner = @img(, LoginBannerImg, 450px, 90px)@ //new

96 LoginFooterColor =  color:@darken(AppC,55)@;
97 LoginErrorPanel =  background-color:#FF9; padding:5px; @roundCorners(8px)@
...
```

Eventhough I have changed the value `36px` to `90px` at line `95`, it shows my custom login image at 36px height still. It is shown well on Internet Explorer, the image's whole view is not showed on Mozilla Firefox.

After page loads I have this `CSS` code at file `/css/common,login,zhtml,skin.css?skin=serenity&v=131203105340` :

```
.ImgLoginBanner{
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url(/skins/_base/logos/LoginBanner_white.png?v=131203105340);
    width:450px;
    height:36px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have restarted the server. It is ok now.

Answer (score 1):

Just for ease - instead of restarting the server, this would have done the job immediately:

```
zmmailboxdctl restart
```